# S2S Vpn RRAS to Azure, joined machine cant connect to azure

Tags: windows, vpn, azure

I have ws22 dc with rras connected to azure with s2s vpn. From ws22 I can rdp to vm that is in azure.

I have other local machine on same network (rras side) but it cant connect to azure.

I have no idea about what  I need to do, Im new to networking.

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled NAT (Network Address Translation) on the Routing and Remote Access Server, so everything on the internal private subnet will send over the VPN? This article explains it very well: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:p_-mIDTesxsJ:https://charbelnemnom.com/create-site-to-site-vpn-between-azure-and-windows-rras-server/&cd=3&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl. I would suggest going over it and checking it your enviroment.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I tried and didn't work ((
this two vm are hyperv, rras vm have external swith and internal, the client have only internal switch